# How to write a function that takes a model as an argument in R

Tags: r

Some functions in R can take a model as an argument. For example,the function lm(weight ~ group) takes "weight~group" as an argument and interpret it as "doing regression using weight as Y and group as X". How do I write a function like this?

For example, I have the following data called "GDP_data":
(please run the snippet to show the data table. I don't know how to let it show automatically)

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>City</td> 
    <td>GDP</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>TX</td>
    <td>Austin</td> 
    <td>678</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>TX</td>
    <td>Dallas</td> 
    <td>1035</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>TX</td>
    <td>Houston</td> 
    <td>2035</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td> 
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>NY</td>
    <td>New York</td> 
    <td>10007</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>NY</td>
    <td>Essex</td> 
    <td>2007</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

I'd like to write a function called GDP_sum that can calculate the sum of GDP of all cities in a state. The code GDP_sum(data=GDP_data, GDP~State) should give me a vector of the total GDP in each state.

Comment: The basic task in solving a homework (or real work) question is to break it into steps. First you search SO or with Google for how to make an R dataframe or matrix object from an HTML table, then you search for how to aggregate by category. Then you search for how to work with R formula objects. You do NOT just post a question that say "do my work for me, please".

Comment: The purpose of this question is to learn how to make a function that take a "model" as an argument. I DO NOT need you to do my HW @BondedDust! Cut your negativity. I just made up the example so that people can teach using an example.

Comment: So you didn't really mean to have that thing called a "code snippet" used as input? Then code for `aggregate.formula` would seem to be a complete answer. Type this at the console: `getAnywhere(aggregate.formula)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just thought HTML is a nicer way to show my example data table. But apparently the HTML code is embedded as "Code snippet" rather than displayed an actual table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using `aggregate` on its own.  Here's what I came up with:

```
state <- c("California","Texas","Texas")
city <- c("San Francisco","Dallas","Austin")
GDP <- c(10000,20000,30000)
data <- data.frame(state,city,GDP)

GDP_sum <- function(data1, slice){
  newDf <- aggregate(slice, data = data1, sum)
  return(newDf)
}

GDP_sum(data, GDP~state)

       state   GDP
1 California 10000
2      Texas 50000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I do not need you to solve my example problem, it's trivial for me. I want to know how to make a function that can take a "model" as an argument. I made up the example so that people can understand what I mean and teach me how using the example

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "model".

Comment: He means a `formula` and there already is a base R function named `aggregate.formula`.

Comment: formula! That's the word.