# How to create a function in R that takes two arguments from two lists?

Tags: r, functional-programming, aggregate, plyr, mapply

I want to generate a dataframe with summary statistics (AUC, Gini, RMSE, etc.) from validation of multiple models on multiple datasets. 
I've got `x` number of models (classifiers - gbm, xgb, rf, etc. - all built in `caret` package) that are enclosed in ListOfModels, and `y` number of datasets (dataframes with identical variables over several data points) that are enclosed in ListOfDatasets.

I can create a short version of the desired dataframe by running a custom function `fun_modelStats` (that extracts model stats using model and dataset as arguments) inside `ldply` - but can do so only either over a ListOfModels and just one specific dataset or over a ListOfDatasets and just one specific model, like this:

```
modelStats_by_model <- ldply(ListOfModels, function(model) {
  modelStats <- fun_modelStats(model, B97_2012SU_2013) 
})
```

and

```
modelStats_by_dataset <- ldply(ListOfDatasets, function(dataset) {
  modelStats <- fun_modelStats(gbmFit1, dataset) 
})
```

The resulting dataframe with models' stats has either `x` or `y` number of rows, and I can't get my head around the way of building this dataframe with `x*y` rows, i.e. stats from all models validated on all datasets.

I did experiment with `Map` and `mapply`, and `for loop`, but to no avail. 
Using `Map` I get weird incorrect output:

```
modelStats_all <- Map(fun_modelStats, ListOfModels, ListOfDatasets)
```

The `for loop` does generate the desired output with this code below, but only as plain text in console whereas I need it as a dataframe.

```
for(i in names(ListOfModels)) {
  for(j in names(ListOfDatasets)) {
    modelStats <- fun_modelStats(ListOfModels[[i]], ListOfDatasets[[j]]) 
    print(modelStats) 
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for help!

P.S. Further search at SO ([How to write a function that takes a model as an argument in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360413/how-to-write-a-function-that-takes-a-model-as-an-argument-in-r) - this post, for example) shows that using `aggregate.formula` or `aggregate.data.frame` or `rbind.data.frame` could help, but I can't figure out how.

Here is the solution, in case anyone faces a similar problem:

```
fun_multiModelStats <- function(ListOfModels, ListOfDatasets) {
  multiModelStats <- data.frame()
  for(i in names(ListOfModels)) { 
    for(j in names(ListOfDatasets)) {
      model <- ListOfModels[[i]]
      dataset <- ListOfDatasets[[j]]
      modelStats <- fun_modelStats(model, dataset) 
      modelName <- names(ListOfModels[i]) 
      datasetName <- names(ListOfDatasets[j])
      modelStats <- cbind(modelName, datasetName, modelStats)
      multiModelStats <- rbind(multiModelStats, modelStats)
    }
  }
  return(multiModelStats)
}
```

Yet, I would like to find a solution without double `for` loops but rather with something from the `apply` family of functions.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if you'll modify your `for` loop as following:

```
modelStats <- data.frame()
for(i in names(ListOfModels)) {
  for(j in names(ListOfDatasets)) {
    modelStats[i,j] <- fun_modelStats(ListOfModels[[i]], ListOfDatasets[[j]]) 
    print(modelStats) 
  }
}
```